# NullPointerException custom camera

Tags: android, android-camera

I've tried to follow this tutorial: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#custom-camera

But I'm stuck on a NullPointerException.

I pasted the code to pastebin, so It looks better: http://pastebin.com/315dUhvR

LogCat says that it crashes on line 31:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Create an instance of Camera
    mCamera = getCameraInstance();

    // Create our Preview view and set it as the content of our activity.
    mPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera);
    FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
    preview.addView(mPreview); // line 31 - crashes here
}
```

As you can see, this is the log:

```
01-15 23:02:33.951: E/AndroidRuntime(1124): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-15 23:02:33.951: E/AndroidRuntime(1124): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.provescamera/com.example.provescamera.CameraActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-15 23:02:33.951: E/AndroidRuntime(1124):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
01-15 23:02:33.951: E/AndroidRuntime(1124):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
01-15 23:02:33.951: E/AndroidRuntime(1124):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
01-15 23:02:33.951: E/AndroidRuntime(1124):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
01-15 23:02:33.951: E/AndroidRuntime(1124):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-15 23:02:33.951: E/AndroidRuntime(1124):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-15 23:02:33.951: E/AndroidRuntime(1124):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
01-15 23:02:33.951: E/AndroidRuntime(1124):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-15 23:02:33.951: E/AndroidRuntime(1124):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-15 23:02:33.951: E/AndroidRuntime(1124):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
01-15 23:02:33.951: E/AndroidRuntime(1124):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
01-15 23:02:33.951: E/AndroidRuntime(1124):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-15 23:02:33.951: E/AndroidRuntime(1124): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-15 23:02:33.951: E/AndroidRuntime(1124):     at com.example.provescamera.CameraActivity.onCreate(CameraActivity.java:31)
01-15 23:02:33.951: E/AndroidRuntime(1124):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
01-15 23:02:33.951: E/AndroidRuntime(1124):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
01-15 23:02:33.951: E/AndroidRuntime(1124):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
01-15 23:02:33.951: E/AndroidRuntime(1124):     ... 11 more
```

**I don't really get it, as I just copied this code...
What am I doing wrong?**

**Oh, almost forgot.**

Manifest:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.provescamera"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.provescamera.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    <activity android:name=".CameraActivity"
          android:label="@string/app_name"

          android:screenOrientation="portrait">
          <!-- configure this activity to use landscape orientation -->

          <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And basic_layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
  <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/camera_preview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    />

  <Button
    android:id="@+id/button_capture"
    android:text="Capture"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

**EDIT:**

Its crashing now line 75:

```
mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are using the wrong layout, try:

```
setContentView(R.layout.basic_layout);
```

Comment: This solved the issue. My bad! But now, I've another error. Line 75. mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder); It's throwing a NullPointerException

Comment: Inside `getCameraInstance()` you have a try-catch block but you don't do anything inside catch. I guess that there is an error while fetching your Camera object which keeps `c` and `mCamera` equal to `null`. You should always print out the stack track during development.

Answer (score 1):

Damn. My second edit, problem was that I didn't put all permissions:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Missed last one.

Answer (score 0):

You try to add the camera permission

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />`

And I think you should remove android:required="false" in this line

`<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />`

If you want this app to work in phone without cameras,
 you should handle Exceptions in case of not having cameras.

Comment: Well its just for testing purposes, but totally. The android:required="false" means you'll have to handle devices without camera.